# Ajax request, fetch JS array and make it available

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I'm trying to fetch a JS array created by a PHP file and re-use the JS array in a JS script in the page. I have tried many different solutions found on this site but none seems to work but I don't know what the issue is with my script.

I have a PHP file that echoes the following:

```
[["content11", "content12", "content13", "content14","content15"], 
 ["content21", "content22", "content23", "content24","content25"]]
```

I'm using a simple Ajax get to retrieve the data:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: myUrlToPhpFile,
      dataType: "html",
      success : function(data) 
          {
              result = data;
              alert (result);

          }
    });
```

The alert displays the expected output from the PHP file but if I now try to access the array like result[0], it outputs "[" which is the first character. It looks like JS sees the output as a string rather than an array.

Is there something I should do to make JS understand it's a JS array?

I have seen many solution with JSON arrays but before going into this direction, I'd like to check if there are simple solutions with JS arrays (this would prevent me from rewriting too much code)

Thanks
Laurent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you php file you need check that your arrays echos with json_encode.

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

And in your javascript file:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: myUrlToPhpFile,
  dataType: "html", // json
  success : function(data) 
      {
         var res = JSON.parse(html);
         alert(html); // show raw data
         alert(res); // show parsed JSON
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to format the string back into an array.

```
JSON.parse(result)[0]
```

or

```
var result = JSON.parse(result);
result[0];
```

Comment: Hello Rho, thanks! I tried this option and by using alert(result[0]) I get content11 up to content 15 but if I use alert(result[0][1]) I get the same instead of getting content12. Is there a way to access this element?

Comment: No problem :). result[0][1] works fine when I play around with it. Can you provide a jsfiddle to replicate your issue?

Answer (score 1):

@Rho's answer should work fine, but it appears that  you're using jQuery for your AJAX call, which gives you a shortcut; you can use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) instead of `$.ajax`, and it will read the data as JSON and provide you with the array immediately.

```
$.getJSON(myUrlToPhpFile, function(result) { ... });
```

This is really just a short way of writing what you already have, but with a `dataType` of `json` instead of `html`, so you could even do it that way if you prefer. This is all assuming that you're using jQuery of course, but your code was following their API so it seems a good bet that you're either using jQuery or something compatible.